# Spring CXF Soap Client OAuth2 Client Credentials

Tags: java, soap, oauth-2.0, cxf

I want to consume a SOAP Web service which requires an OAuth2 authentication with client_credentials grant type.

From the documentation (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-oauth2.html#JAX-RSOAuth2-AdvancedOAuth2clientapplications) , I have found the `BearerAuthSupplier` which could be usefull. So I tried

```java
    @Bean
    public CustomName customName()
    {

        final JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setServiceClass(CustomName.class);
        factoryBean.setAddress("");
        final CustomName serviceClient = (CustomName ) factoryBean.create();

        // Get the underlying Client object from the proxy object of service interface
        final org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client proxy = ClientProxy.getClient(serviceClient);

        final HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) proxy.getConduit();

        final BearerAuthSupplier supplier = new BearerAuthSupplier();
        supplier.setAccessTokenServiceUri("");
        supplier.setConsumer(new Consumer("client-id", "client-secret"));
        supplier.setRefreshEarly(true);
        conduit.setAuthSupplier(supplier);

        return serviceClient;


    }
```

In the Authorization Header I had a `Basic` assertion (I wanted a `Bearer`). Plus, I had no possibility to set the scope of the token. I think there is something I missed ...

To get this working, I had to extend `BearerAuthSupplier` to somethink like this

```java
public class CustomAuthSupplier extends BearerAuthSupplier {

    private String accessTokenServiceUri;

    public String getAuthorization(AuthorizationPolicy authPolicy,
                                   URI currentURI,
                                   Message message,
                                   String fullHeader) {

        ClientCredentialsGrant clientCredentialsGrant = new ClientCredentialsGrant("scope_needed");
        clientCredentialsGrant.setClientId(this.getConsumer().getClientId());
        clientCredentialsGrant.setClientSecret(this.getConsumer().getClientSecret());

        WebClient wc = WebClient.create(this.accessTokenServiceUri, Collections.singletonList(new OAuthJSONProvider()));
        ClientAccessToken at = OAuthClientUtils.getAccessToken(wc,clientCredentialsGrant);
        this.setClientAccessToken(at);

        return super.getAuthorization(authPolicy, currentURI, message, fullHeader);
    }

    public void setAccessTokenServiceUri(String uri) {
        this.accessTokenServiceUri = uri;
        super.setAccessTokenServiceUri(uri);
    }
```

So far it works well, but I find it a bit complicated (and I'm not really sure of what i am doing). My question is : How to perform client credential grant with CXF when calling a Soap WS ?